# How can I upload a file to php using JQuery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery

Does anyone know any good tutorial on how to upload a file with php by using jQuery and ajax?

Comment: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/

Comment: possible duplicate of [upload file using ajax,jquery,php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768533/upload-file-using-ajax-jquery-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an all good

[http://www.plupload.com/](http://www.plupload.com)

and there are some examples

http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php

If you download it inside the .zip there is a folder called examples
and in this folder you can find the upload.php.
This is how its processing the sent file.